# How to keep inputing the frequency and duration till 100 values only and retreive them

Tags: c

The user can only enter a 100 values maximum for both the duration and frequency, so how do we have the user keep entering them continuously and retrieve them from the arrays, when they wish to play the song? I'm not sure about my code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;


    char menu = 0, a, A, b, B, c, C;
    int duration[100];  
    float frequency[100];   

    if (menu != 'c' || menu != 'C')
    {
        while (menu != 'c' || menu != 'C') 

        {
            printf("a. Build the song\n");
            printf("b. Play the song\n");
            printf("c. Quit\n");
            printf("Please enter an option: ");
            scanf(" %c", &menu);


            if (menu == 'A' || menu == 'a')
            {

                printf("Please enter a frequency: ");
                scanf("%f", &frequency[i] + 1);


                printf("Please enter a duration: ");
                scanf("%d", &duration[i] + 1);
                system("cls");
            }



            else if (menu == 'b' || menu == 'B')

            {

                Beep(frequency[i], duration[i]);

                system("cls");

            }
            else if (menu == 'c' || menu == 'C')
            {
                return 0;
            }


        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: Yes it does compile perfectly but I'm just doubtful on it storing into the arrays and playing correctly

Comment: You aren't incrementing `i`. What do you believe `&frequency[i] + 1` is doing?

Comment: adding values that the user enters into the arrays and keeping on storing it further

Comment: Well `&frequency[i]` is the address of `frequency[i]`. In this case thats `frequency[0]` since `i` is never modified. Then adding one to that address gives the address of `frequency[1]` so all the results are being stored at `frequency[1]`.

Comment: so would frequency[1] help adding more elements?

Comment: I don't even know what that means. I think you should probably go study the basics of arrays and pointers.

Comment: I mean to have the user keep adding the frequency and duration into arrays with a limit of 100 elements and retrieve those elements in option b, which says to play the duration and frequency

Comment: The outer `if` is **completely useless**, since the `while` has the exact same condition.

Comment: The Windows Beep function does not take floats.  It expects a pair of DWORD, which is really uint32_t, but they go to all the trouble of aliasing a standard type, so you should use DWORD as your frequency and duration values.

Comment: `menu != 'c' || menu != 'C'` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of your code:

```
    if (menu == 'A' || menu == 'a')
    {

        printf("Please enter a frequency: ");
        scanf("%f", &frequency[i] + 1);

        printf("Please enter a duration: ");
        scanf("%d", &duration[i] + 1);
        system("cls");
    }
```

I see these problems:

1) You never incremt `i` (something you should do every time a new tone is added)

2) You do `+ 1` to the address

3) You don't check for max 100 tones

4) You don't check the return value from `scanf`

You can fix it like:

```
    if (menu == 'A' || menu == 'a')
    {
        if (i < 100)
        {
            printf("Please enter a frequency: ");
            if (scanf("%f", &frequency[i]) == 1)
            {
                printf("Please enter a duration: ");
                if (scanf("%d", &duration[i]) == 1)
                {
                    // Tone added - increment i
                    ++i;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Illegal dureation\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Illegal frequency\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You already have 100 tones\n");
        }
    }
```

Note: It will probably be good to rename `i` to a more descriptive name. e.g. `numTones`